# onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave to animate multiple Lottie icons in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, animation, lottie

I have written the following code to animate three Lottie icons in a Gatsby project. The code works as expected: the icon starts moving when the user hovers on the element and stops playing when the element is not hovered anymore. Is there a way though to reuse the same function for onMouseLeave and onMouseEnter to animate all three icons (not all at once but separately)? Right now I have specified different functions for each icon but it feels like the code could be shorter.

```
import React, { createRef, useEffect } from "react"
import lottie from "lottie-web"
import heart from "../assets/data/heart.json"
import wine from "../assets/data/wine.json"
import party from "../assets/data/party.json"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

export const query = graphql`
  {
    contentfulMatrimonio {
      titolo
      sottotitolo
    }
  }
`

const Wedding = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(query)

  let animationContainer1 = createRef()
  let animationContainer2 = createRef()
  let animationContainer3 = createRef()

  let heartPlay = null
  let winePlay = null
  let partyPlay = null

  useEffect(() => {
    let heartIcon = {
      container: animationContainer1.current,
      animationData: heart, //animation file
      renderer: "svg",
      loop: true,
      autoplay: false,
    }

    let wineIcon = {
      container: animationContainer2.current,
      animationData: wine, //animation file
      renderer: "svg",
      loop: true,
      autoplay: false,
    }
    let partyIcon = {
      container: animationContainer3.current,
      animationData: party, //animation file
      renderer: "svg",
      loop: true,
      autoplay: false,
    }

    heartPlay = lottie.loadAnimation(heartIcon)
    winePlay = lottie.loadAnimation(wineIcon)
    partyPlay = lottie.loadAnimation(partyIcon)
  }, [])

  function startHeartAnimation() {
    heartPlay.play()
  }

  function stopHeartAnimation() {
    heartPlay.pause()
  }

  function startWineAnimation() {
    winePlay.play()
  }

  function stopWineAnimation() {
    winePlay.pause()
  }

  function startPartyAnimation() {
    partyPlay.play()
  }

  function stopPartyAnimation() {
    partyPlay.pause()
  }

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className="title-container">
        <h3>{data.contentfulMatrimonio.titolo}</h3>
        <p>{data.contentfulMatrimonio.sottotitolo}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="program-container">
        <StaticImage
          src="../assets/images/spots.png"
          placeholder="tracedSVG"
          layout="constrained"
          className="background-style"
        />
        <div
          className="program-card"
          onMouseEnter={startHeartAnimation}
          onMouseLeave={stopHeartAnimation}
        >
          <div className="animation-container" ref={animationContainer1}></div>
          <p className="time-style">ore 17:00</p>
          <p>cerimonia</p>
        </div>
        <div
          className="program-card"
          onMouseEnter={startWineAnimation}
          onMouseLeave={stopWineAnimation}
        >
          <div className="animation-container" ref={animationContainer2}></div>
          <p className="time-style">ore 19:00</p>
          <p>cena</p>
        </div>
        <div
          className="program-card"
          onMouseEnter={startPartyAnimation}
          onMouseLeave={stopPartyAnimation}
        >
          <div className="animation-container" ref={animationContainer3}></div>
          <p className="time-style">ore 22:00</p>
          <p>tutti si balla</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling Events,you can bind event with param by using arrow function, like this.

```
  const Hello = () => {
    const startWineAnimation = (param) => {
        switch (param) {
        case 1:
            //do div1
            break;
        case 2:
            //do div2
            break;
        case 3:
            //do div3
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
        <div className="div1" onMouseEnter={() => startWineAnimation(1)}>
            123
        </div>
        <div className="div2" onMouseEnter={() => startWineAnimation(2)}>
            456
        </div>
        <div className="div3" onMouseEnter={() => startWineAnimation(3)}>
            789
        </div>
        </div>
    );
    };
```